# How to get URL for Jenkins build by SHA or branch?

Tags: git, jenkins

I found how to get XLM and JSON data from the Jenkins api using URLs like `/api/xml` and `/api/json`.

And, to get the SHA of the last build: `/lastBuild/api/xml?xpath=//lastBuiltRevision/SHA1`.

I looked at `/api/xml`, and it does not seem to expose the SHA or branch. Only job number and Jenkins URL.

So, Given a SHA or branch name, how to get the Jenkins URL associated to that SHA or branch?